# Thread-pool configuration in Jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I want to have more information on how configuring the Thread-pool in JBoss. My aim is to have a server that can treat as many queries as possible at the same time.

Comment: > My aim is to have a server that can treat as many queries as possible at the same time.


This is generally not a good idea. Often you get better performance with a smaller pool and a bit of queueing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that in JBoss EAP 7+ you don't have the `server.xml` anymore, so then you just need to edit your `standalone.xml` or `domain.xml` to include the max number of threads:

```
<!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="300" />
```

I'm talking here about **Undertow threads**, which are shared with EJB.

There is also the IO threads that are using to connect with DB for example.